# How to use the Eigen-unsupported NNLS (non negative least square) class

Tags: c++, eigen

When I tried to build a very sample application using the unsupported Eigen::NNLS, it appeared the class refers method internal::householder_qr_inplace_update which I cannot find anywhere.

here is the program I tried to compile:

```
#include "Eigen/Core"
#include "unsupported/Eigen/NNLS"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;

int main()
{

    auto matrix = Eigen::Matrix<double, 3, 3>{
        { 1.0, 2.0, 1.0 }, 
        { 2.0, -1.0, 1.0 },
        { 3.0, 4.0, 1.0 },
    };

    auto b = Eigen::Vector<double, 3>{ 1.0, 2.0, 1.0 };
    auto x = NNLS<Eigen::Matrix<double,3,3>>(matrix);   
    auto res = x.solve(b);

    std::cout << res << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is error message returned by vs2022

```
>------ Build All started: Project: testEigenUnsupportNNLS, Configuration: x64-debug ------
  [1/2] Building CXX object testEigenUnsupportNNLS\CMakeFiles\testEigenUnsupportNNLS.dir\testEigenUnsupportNNLS.cpp.obj
  FAILED: testEigenUnsupportNNLS/CMakeFiles/testEigenUnsupportNNLS.dir/testEigenUnsupportNNLS.cpp.obj 
  C:\PROGRA~1\MICROS~4\2022\PROFES~1\VC\Tools\MSVC\1436~1.325\bin\Hostx64\x64\cl.exe  /nologo /TP  -IC:\DEV\git\cdi\testEigenUnsupportNNLS\..\..\..\3rdParty\eigen\eigen-3.4.0 -IC:\DEV\git\cdi\testEigenUnsupportNNLS\..\..\..\3rdParty\eigen\eigen-3.4.0\unsupported /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3 /GR /EHsc /MDd /Ob0 /Od /RTC1 -std:c++20 -ZI /showIncludes /FotestEigenUnsupportNNLS\CMakeFiles\testEigenUnsupportNNLS.dir\testEigenUnsupportNNLS.cpp.obj /FdtestEigenUnsupportNNLS\CMakeFiles\testEigenUnsupportNNLS.dir\ /FS -c C:\DEV\git\cdi\testEigenUnsupportNNLS\testEigenUnsupportNNLS\testEigenUnsupportNNLS.cpp
C:\DEV\3rdParty\eigen\eigen-3.4.0\unsupported\Eigen\NNLS(345): error C2039: 'householder_qr_inplace_update': is not a member of 'Eigen::internal'
  C:\DEV\3rdParty\eigen\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen\src\QR\CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition.h(593): note: see declaration of 'Eigen::internal'
C:\DEV\3rdParty\eigen\eigen-3.4.0\unsupported\Eigen\NNLS(357): error C2039: 'householder_qr_inplace_update': is not a member of 'Eigen::internal'
  C:\DEV\3rdParty\eigen\eigen-3.4.0\Eigen\src\QR\CompleteOrthogonalDecomposition.h(593): note: see declaration of 'Eigen::internal'
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.

Build All failed.
```

I realize though this class has been added quite recently (march 2022) and most recent release is from July 2021.

Comment: Did you try with an up-to-date Eigen-master version?

Comment: This class has not been packaged yet from what I saw. I first felt on the eigen documentation page, then got the source from github. The official latest release of eigen does not include this code yet

Comment: The latest development version of Eigen is at gitlab (not github): https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/

Comment: @chtz. thanks.. indeed, writing my comment I realized I should have look to the missing part in the repo. and indeed everything is there. Spent probably too much of time trying to grasp the idea behind the algo

Comment: how can I close this  fairly useless question?

Comment: hi, the function `internal::householder_qr_inplace_update` is located in [Eigen/src/QR/HouseholderQR.h](https://gitlab.com/libeigen/eigen/-/blob/master/Eigen/src/QR/HouseholderQR.h?ref_type=heads#L376)
you can just copy this function to NNLS file to use NNLS solver

Comment: @LeeDavid, thx this is well the response I was chasing. thx to come back at it